# RestHighLevelClient Bean for elasticsearch not found on classpath in spring boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to upgrade my existing spring boot 2.7.x project to spring boot 3.x.x.
I have sorted out everything except this error while running the application.

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of method lockProvider in com.cox.config.ShedLockConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient' in your configuration.

Process finished with exit code 0

Spring Boot Version used is 3.0.0
I am aware that RestHighLevelClient is deprecated, but documentation says it's still available in spring-data-elasticsearch

Tried upgrading all dependencies to be compatible with spring boot 3

**Update:**
Also getting below error for another component with elastic search which I am trying to upgrade to spring boot 3

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 2 of constructor in com.cox.service.esindex.EsIndexRefreshService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations' in your configuration.

It looks like spring boot is no longer creating beans for deprecated methods/classes. Can you please help me map each deprecated method/class with the new spring-data-elasticsearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch-migration-guide-4.4-5.0.old-client) explicitly states:

> The old deprecated RestHighLevelClient can still be used, but you will need to add the dependency explicitly to your application as Spring Data Elasticsearch does not pull it in automatically anymore:

**Edit 18.02.2023:**

Check the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.resthighlevelclient) it also documents how to configure the different clients. You will have to do this configuraiton by yourself, I don't think that Spring Boot will configure this automatically, they are using the current stuff from Spring Data Elasticsearch .

Comment: I have added the following dependency as per doc, but still the same error appears. Do I have to add any config for it to provide bean automatically ?
`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.17.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>`

Comment: However, my elasticsearch cluster is in remote server with https host which refuses to connect with this manual configuration. Prior to this spring boot upgrade spring was creating RestHighLevelClient automatically without any configuration and it was connecting to remote https elasticsearch successfully. If you know any possible ways to solve this do let me know.

Comment: Getting below error
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known (https://[url of elastic search node]:9200)
 at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:933)
 at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1529)

Comment: Ok, I've resolved that error by adding .usingSsl() option, However it's appending 9200 by default which is causing timeout error. I don't need any port number to be appended in my elasticsearch cluster url. Any idea how to achieve that behavior ?

Comment: adding port 443?

Comment: Thanks adding 443 as port gives successful connection to elastic search.
But now facing different error for which I've raised another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75528682/elasticsearch-exception-type-exception-reason-content-type-header-application