# Elasticsearch exception [type=exception, reason=Content-Type header [application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=7]

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Getting the below error while running spring boot version 3.0.0 application with elastic search.

```
 Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException:
 Elasticsearch exception [type=exception, reason=Content-Type header [application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=7] is not supported]
```

I am trying to upgrade springboot from *2.6.9* to *3.0.x*, which resulted in the above error for elastic search.
(Prior to spring boot upgrade elasticsearch was working fine)

**Version used before spring-boot upgrade**

- spring boot version 2.6.9
- spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch 2.6.9
- spring-data-elasticsearch 4.4.0
- elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client 7.17.3
- elasticsearch server version 7.9.3

**Version used after spring-boot upgrade**

- spring boot version 3.0.0
- spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch 3.0.0
- spring-data-elasticsearch 5.0.0
- elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client 7.17.3
- elasticsearch server version 7.9.3

Comment: did you set the header in the old version as well?

Comment: No I didn't and I am not setting headers manually in this version either.

Comment: I suppose the rest-high-level-client uses the elasticsearch-low-level client in version 8.6 which adds this header. This header was introduced with 7.10 i f I remember correctly. Try to fix the version of the org.elasticsearch.restclient dependency to 7.17.3 as well. Or upgrade your cluster to 8, the RestHighLevelClient is deprecated for over a year now.

Comment: I have low level rest-client also on version 7.17.3 and it still gives the same error. Upgrading the cluster is not an option for me that is handled by different team.

Comment: One interesting thing to note here is that before springboot upgrade this header is not causing any issues despite elasticsearch client being on 7.17.x and server on 7.9.x.

Comment: Root Cause: Suppressed: org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host [https://[myhost]:443], URI [/fs_gpscourier_kvstore/_search?typed_keys=true&max_concurrent_shard_requests=5&search_type=query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512], status line [HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable]
{"error":"Content-Type header [application/vnd.elasticsearch+json; compatible-with=7] is not supported","status":406}

For the record, few GET calls on elasticsearch before this error are working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the code of Spring Data Elasticsearch why and under which circumstances this header is sent in version 5.0.0:

1. When using the old reactive client implementation (the new one uses the same transport function as the new ElasticsearchClient). As this old reactive client only was built with Elasticsearch 7 compatibility it now sets this header.
2. When the new ElasticsearchClient is created (this was already possible in 4.4 with Elasticsearch 7.17 or a few versions earlier, although optional). When now building the transport for the new client, this header is set to the version of the used library. This transport is used for the new reactive client as well.

You are referencing a dependency of the RestHighLevelClient, but that code does not send this header, so you are probably reactive or using the new client. How is your client set up, which client class do you use?

The main problem however is that the version of Elasticsearch server you use is more than two years old (7.9.3 was released on October 22nd 2020) and does not understand this header. The last Spring Data Elasticsearch version using that Elasticsearch dependency was 4.1, 4.2 already was built against 7.12.0.

Comment: I've added my configuration as an answer below. This is the only way I am setting my client. (Before spring boot upgrade this was not present, earlier it was just elasticsearch details in the properties/yml file)

Comment: @UdayPatil your configuration should better be added to your question. You can edit your question and add more context to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Configuration    
    public class RestClientConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {  
      
    @Override  
    @Bean("RestHighLevelClient")  
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {  
  
        final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()  
                .connectedTo("myhost:443")  
                .usingSsl()  
                .withBasicAuth("myuser", "mypass")  
                .build();  
  
        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();  
    }  
}
```

This is the only configuration I have !!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).